# What does this TypeErrorImpl error mean to be in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I am getting or throwing error called TypeErrorImpl in many situation using flutter framework.

So, here i am not understanding the error meaning likem, what exactly the situation or why the error is throwing. What can be the mistake is or What does this error mean to be?

For example:

- Getting this error while fetching data from DB (Firebase).
- getting error while storing into the DB.
- while displaying some images.

But after refreshing the project error will not throw for sometimes.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I get this error in Flutter when I am decoding json data, and I claim a Object as String when it is actually null. My cheap fix is adding a null check on my values.